# What digitally encoded smell formats exist?

Tags: sensation

Is there a defacto format for storing and transmitting smell digitally? Where can I obtain samples of such smell encodings? What reference dataset exists against which I can compare my smell sample to determine it might be the scent of an 'orange' or other scent?

There seems to be a lot of mostly theoretical material about how smell can be analysed, but little if any actual digital samples or reference data for conducting concrete experiments on that data.

Comment: hilarious tomd (for a 5 year old), only serious replies would be appreciated